# bootsfaces selectMultiMenu don't show selected values

Tags: multi-select, bootsfaces

I want to pre-charge a selectMultiMenu with values I already have in the application.

For example:

```
<b:panelGrid colSpans="2,2,8">
<h:outputLabel value="Traffic light color" />
<b:selectMultiMenu value="#{semaphoreBean.color}"  >
    <f:selectItems value="#{semaphoreBean.colors}" var="c" itemValue="#{c}" itemLabel="#{c}"/>
</b:selectMultiMenu>
</b:panelGrid>
```

if var `color = "green, red"` before than I load the page, I don't see in my selectMultiMenu 2 items selected.
¿What do I have to do to pre-load that field with those values?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's because of the space between the entries. I take it you've take the example from our showcase. So I've added this line to our showcase, and it works like charm:

```
      private String color = "green,red";
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out data format was wrong so I fix it and works.
Thank you for helping.